# Break-Inside and Break-After not working

Tags: css

I have a list of titles and definitions:

```
<dl>
<dt>Item 1</dt>
<dd>Nulla at neque blandit, pretium sapien vitae, ornare neque.</dd>
<dt>Item 2</dt>
<dd>Quisque fermentum augue nec rutrum suscipit.</dd>
<dt>Item 3</dt>
<dd>Sed facilisis eros ac lorem bibendum, id tristique ipsum rhoncus.</dd>
<dt>Item 4</dt>
<dd>Duis scelerisque risus sit amet metus placerat volutpat.</dd>
<dt>Item 5</dt>
<dd>Duis tristique erat at leo lacinia, nec fringilla risus rhoncus.</dd>
<dt>Item 6</dt>
<dd>Cras rutrum eros dictum nulla tempus, in consequat tellus dignissim.</dd>
<dt>Item 7</dt>
<dd>Maecenas et erat vitae metus euismod luctus.</dd>
```

If the browser is wide enough, I'd like to present this in a multi column layout. I'm able to do that, however, I'd like column breaks to happen only after s and never in the middle of s and s, or after s.

Right now I'm using:

```
dl{column-count:2}
dt,dd{break-inside:avoid;column-break-inside:avoid;-webkit-column-break-inside:avoid}
dt{break-after:never;column-break-after:never;-webkit-column-break-after:never}
```

At least in chrome this doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Try adding the older property names as well: **page**-break-after , "page-break-*" ?  ... in any case I think only firefox supports these properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put dt and dd into a div. Moreover, you have to use `break-inside` also for this div. Note that you have to use also other declaration for compatibility trough browsers. For example, you have to add `page-break-inside` for Firefox. See [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/break-inside/) for further examples. See also the snippet.

I hope I was of any help.

```css
dl {
  column-count: 2
}

dt,
dd,
.all {
  break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid
}

dt {
  break-after: never;
  column-break-after: never;
  -webkit-column-break-after: never
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <div class="all">
    <dt>Item 1</dt>
    <dd>Nulla at neque blandit, pretium sapien vitae, ornare neque.</dd>
  </div>
  <div class="all">
    <dt>Item 2</dt>
    <dd>Quisque fermentum augue nec rutrum suscipit.</dd>
  </div>
  <div class="all">
    <dt>Item 3</dt>
    <dd>Sed facilisis eros ac lorem bibendum, id tristique ipsum rhoncus.</dd>
  </div>
  <div class="all">
    <dt>Item 4</dt>
    <dd>Duis scelerisque risus sit amet metus placerat volutpat.</dd>
  </div>
  <div class="all">
    <dt>Item 5</dt>
    <dd>Duis tristique erat at leo lacinia, nec fringilla risus rhoncus.</dd>
  </div>
  <div class="all">
    <dt>Item 6</dt>
    <dd>Cras rutrum eros dictum nulla tempus, in consequat tellus dignissim.</dd>
  </div>
  <div class="all">
    <dt>Item 7</dt>
    <dd>Maecenas et erat vitae metus euismod luctus.</dd>
  </div>
</dl>
```